# Excel vba copying sheets different workbook format

Tags: vba, excel, copy, range

Can anyone assist explaining why my range does not update completely and how I can force that?
The range of cells updates but the focus remains on the same sheet. It then fails when it reaches the next line where it has to copy.

```
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="U:\T\A.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever

    dblLastRow = 1 + Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Z").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngReport2 = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Report2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(dblLastRow, 7))
    rngReport2.Copy
    Workbooks("B.xls").Worksheets("Y").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)


    dblLastRow = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Sector code").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngReport2 = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Sector code").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(dblLastRow, 3))
    rngReport2.Copy
    Workbooks("B.xls").Worksheets("X").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always qualify your `Cells()` with a worksheet reference:

```
Sub test()

    Dim wbA As Workbook, wbB As Workbook
    Dim dblLastRow As Long

    Set wbA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="U:\T\A.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever)
    Set wbB = Workbooks("B.xls")

    With wbA.Worksheets("Report2")
        dblLastRow = 1 + .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        CopyValues .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(dblLastRow, 7)), wbB.Worksheets("Y").Range("A1")
    End With

    With wbA.Worksheets("Sector code")
        dblLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        CopyValues .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(dblLastRow, 3)), wbB.Worksheets("X").Range("A1")
    End With

End Sub

Sub CopyValues(rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range)
    rngDest.Cells(1).Resize(rngSrc.Rows.Count, _
             rngSrc.Columns.Count).Value = rngSrc.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I am not a fan of function but since I had to reiterate the action with other ranges a few more times, it did make sense :)